# Iterating in a python numpy matrix - adding and subtracting to cell elements gone wrong

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, iteration

Input is a numpy matrix and the procedure is to find all entries above 3 in the matrix. When the program has found an entry with a value of 4 or higher, the program must subtract 4 from that matrix position and distribute that 4 - one to the cell above, one to the cell below, one to the cell to the left and one to the cell to the right.

Input is [ [3,3,3], [3,4,3], [3,3,3] ], and I expect an output of [ [3,4,3], [4,0,4], [3,4,3] ].

Instead I get [ [3,4,4], [4,2,1], [4,1,1] ]

The 4 in the middle of the input matrix needs to be taken out and redistributed to the adjacent cell elements of the matrix; one above, one below, one to the left and one to the right.
This does not happen. I cannot make sense of it. Anyone, please.

I added some constraints - so that if an entry in the matrix does have an entry of 4 or larger close to the boundary of the matrix - this will make sure that you add one only to existing entries in the matrix.

```
import numpy as np

dimension = 3
abba = np.matrix( [ [3,3,3], [3,4,3], [3,3,3] ] )


# implement the rules


def sandpile(field):

    for x in range(dimension):
        for y in range (dimension):

            if field[x,y] > 3:
                field[x,y] = field[x,y] - 4

            if x+1 < dimension:
                field[x+1,y] = field[x+1,y] + 1

            if x-1 >= 0:
                field[x-1,y] = field[x-1,y] + 1

            if y-1 >= 0:
                field[x,y-1] = field[x,y-1] + 1


            if y+1 < dimension:
                field[x,y+1] = field[x,y+1] + 1

    return (field) 


print(abba)
abba = sandpile(abba)
print(abba)
```

Comment: Because you are altering the input matrix while iterating over it. You should make a separate output matrix before the iteration, as a copy of the input matrix, and alter that, while using the input matrix for your if-test.

Comment: Also, since addition with 1 should only happen when the input element is larger than 3, you should indent the last four if statements: they should be part of the first if statement. Currently, they will always happen (if their condition is true), whether the input cell is larger than 3 or not.

Comment: you are right - I see now ... thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the approaches with slight change in your existing code:

```
import numpy as np

dimension = 3
abba = np.array( [ [3,3,3], [3,4,3], [3,3,3] ] )
done = False
for i in range(dimension):
    for j in range(dimension):
        if (abba[i][j]) >= 4:
            abba[i][j] -= 4
            if i>0:
                abba[i-1][j] += 1
            if i<dimension-1:
                abba[i+1][j] += 1
            if j>0:
                abba[i][j-1] += 1
            if j<dimension-1:
                abba[i][j+1] += 1
            done = True
            break
    if done:
        break
            
print (abba)
```

Output:

```
[[3 4 3]
 [4 0 4]
 [3 4 3]]
```

Comment: thank you - much appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation using `np.where` and assuming periodic boundaries. If you want the additions to 'leak' out of the matrix you have to filter out the right, left, top, bottom conditions accordingly.

```py
import numpy as np
dimx, dimy = 3, 3
a = np.random.randint(0, 5, (dimx, dimy))
greater3 = np.where(a > 3)
print(a)
left = (greater3[0], greater3[1]-1)
right = (greater3[0], (greater3[1]-1) % dimy)
top = (greater3[0] - 1, greater3[1])
bottom = ((greater3[1]-1) % dimx, greater3[1])

a[greater3] -= 4
a[left] += 1
a[right] += 1
a[top] += 1
a[bottom] += 1

print(a)
```